# No appropriate method, property, or field path for class Matlab

Tags: matlab

I keep getting this error from this line of code:

```
  result = simplify_path(obj.path_(mlength -2), obj.path_(mlength-1), obj.path(mlength));
```

result is just a temp variable and the everything has already been defined and works at other places in the code.

simplify_path is a function I defined elsewhere in another file. It is NOT method of my class. I made sure that everything is spelled correctly.

What is going on?

Comment: I'm guessing that `obj.path_` should actually be `obj.path`, without the underscore. Without knowing anything else about `obj` or its methods, there's not much more we can suggest you try.

Comment: nope. it's supposed to be there. someone else wrote that. not sure why, though.

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Please show the whole thing. Also, is it possible that this is due to the space in front of the minus sign here: `obj.path_(mlength -2)`?

Comment: See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206816/error-using-simple-matrix-multiplication) in case the space issue fixes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
result = simplify_path(obj.path_(mlength -2), ...
                       obj.path_(mlength-1),...
                       obj.path_(mlength));
```

Comment: mmm. this works. so I've checked the answer. But why does this work, and why didn't my way work.

Comment: @lars look at the final argument of the function: your code reads `obj.path` while my answer reads `obj.path_`. it's all in the details...